# while loop in callback function causes crash in p5.js

Tags: javascript, callback, p5.js

when I program this piece of code: 
[code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4dd913789f5d38bf9af7f5f285f9b021)

I encounter some problem.

The result I want is to display a recursive tree on the scree, just like
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jjeOYMjmDU&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZiZxtDDRCi6uhfTH4FilpH&index=17)

But instead of showing the tree by lines directly, I want to show the graph point by point and after a branch is finished then render another branch. (just like animation showing the rendering process)

In the beginning, I use `setInterval()` (you can see it in the code and I comment it out), but after I google it, I discover the sync async problem, so I use callback function.

Based on my realization, if i use callback function, the whole code will wait there for the finish of callback function.

and in the callback function, i use `while` to achieve the "point by point" effect with `frameCount` built in p5.js

I think there're some problem here, maybe owing to `while` loop is too busy?

*update:
if code is set to `if(count == 20)` will cause error. The reason I set count to 10 is because I want dot showing like animation. because initial frameCount is 0, so count set to 0 will not cause error and can render the picture successfully.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/soulert/pen/jYdpxK)

```
while(true) {
    // if count == 10 will cause error
        if(count == 0) {
            console.log(count);
            point(0, y);
            y += dy;
            console.log(frameCount);
        }
        if(y < -1 * len) {
            console.log('break');
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of posting links to external websites.

Comment: I think you're right! But because callback function related, it is not that readable if I omit some part of codes. I update the post and provide the codepen link, so other people can directly change the code and see what it is!